# Highlight text ignoring cases in word document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, highlight

With the below code am able to highlight search text. But if the search text is "also" then "Also" is not getting highlighted. How to ignore cases.

```
 foreach (Word.Range w in doc.Words)
                            {

                                for (int i = 1; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
                                {

                                    XmlAttributeCollection xmlattrc = xmlnode[i].Attributes;
                                    object text = xmlnode[i].FirstChild.InnerText;

                                    if (w.Text.Trim() == text.ToString())
                                    {
                                        w.Font.Bold = 1;
                                        w.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: You have asked this before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421010/highlight-a-text-in-word-document-in-c-sharp-ignoring-cases) and you got a right answer and a properly-working code. You should mark that answer as the right one and use that code. If now you want to try a different approach and don't know how to deal with caps in a standard comparison, you should focused your question on this matter (= "how can I compare two strings independently upon caps; e.g., thisstring being equal to ThiSstrinG"?); nothing to do with Word or Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use the string Compare method:

```
if(String.Compare(w.Text.Trim(), text.ToString(), true) == 0)
```

Comment: If you're concerned with culture specifics, you should this version of Compare: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
       // int counter = 0;
        object readOnly = true;
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
         new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\noor\Desktop\HIGH LIGHTER\Sample.txt");
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        //string textToFind  = "to";
        //string my = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\noor\Desktop\HIGH LIGHTER\Sample.txt");
        //var textToFind = my ;
       // textBox1.Text = textToFind.ToString ();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
            object missing = System.Type.Missing;
            doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            string ReadValue = string.Empty;
            // Activate the document
            doc.Activate();

            /* foreach (Word.Range tmpRange in doc.StoryRanges)
             {
                 ReadValue += tmpRange.Text;
             }
         */
            foreach (Word.Range docRange in doc.Words)
                try
                {

                    if (docRange.Text.Trim().Equals(line, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == false )
                    {
                        docRange.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
                        docRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdWhite;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
                }
        }
           // counter++;


        file.Close();

    }
```